# Return nil after loop and also in unless block in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a working code as below. Is there any better way to return `nil` after the `each` loop and `unless else` in the below example?

```
def find_member(member_name)
  unless members.empty?
    members.each do |member|
      if member.name == member_name
        return member
      end
    end
    nil
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

I should pass `nil` in each case because there are different conditions in other methods where this method is called. That is the reason why I have written the code as above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby has a `detect` method, so your entire method can be replaced with

```
members.detect { |member| member.name == member_name }
```

As an aside, `each` works fine for empty arrays, hence the `empty?` check you have is completely unnecessary even if you keep the explicit loop.

Comment: Are you the lifter or the liftee?

Answer (score -1):

It's a method on `Enumerable`. It is also aliased to `find` which may be a more descriptive verb depending on the context. Using the built-in functions will always be faster because they are implemented in `c`